# Adding parameters to url on page load only if no paremeters already exist

Tags: javascript

I searched for the answer to my question and even tried some solutions, but wasn't able to get anything to really work. I'm newish to javascript, so that might also be why.

I have a specific URL and whenever someone goes to that URL, I want to add parameters to it, but only if no parameters are already present. Parameters get added to the URL for other on click events, but on page load, I need a set of parameters added to the URL.

I tried to use the history API and I think I'm kind of close, but I'm not able to get it to do what I want it to do.

```
    function addDefaultParam(url) {
        var currentURL = window.location.href; //get the current url
        var baseURL = '/our-partners'; //this is the url that should have params added
        var paramString = '?asc=true&sortBy=display_name'; //here are the params

        if (currentURL === baseURL) { 
            window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/" + paramString); 
            }
            return url;
    }
```

I'm using basic js in this because that's what was used in the other functions (I inherited this code). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not quite understand your question. But maybe you could try the following code. `if (location.pathname === '/our-partners' && !location.search) ...`. See "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location" for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register the `addDefaultParam` function to fire when the document first loads in the browser and use the [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) interface to check the state of the [current path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/pathname) and [query string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search) of the URL and if they match your conditions, update the current query string value.

See below for an example:

```
window.addEventListener("load", addDefaultParam);

function addDefaultParam() {
  let currentPath = document.location.pathname;
  let currentQueryString = document.location.search;

  let targetPath = "/our-partners";

  if (currentPath === targetPath && !currentQueryString) {
    document.location.search = "?asc=true&sortBy=display_name";
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok I figured it out with your help. Thank you!

Comment: @HelpImDumb No worries - if my answer was correct, please go ahead and accept it and if it wasn't let me know so that I can remove it.

Comment: Thank you again!